# filling two arrays at a time in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having trouble copying data from inside a do--while loop and repeating it outside the loop. It is during a split function, where each student's test score is entered on the same line as his/her name. I'm sorry if this is a very simple question but I cannot find anywhere how to fix it. Thanks very much for any help.

```
    do {
        Console.Write("Enter the student's name followed by his/her score on the same line:");
        studentAndScore = Console.ReadLine();
        if (studentAndScore == "")
        {
            break;
        }
        string[] parsedInput;
        parsedInput = studentAndScore.Split();
            string student = parsedInput[0] = students[0];
            score = int.Parse(parsedInput[1]);
            score = studentScores[0];
        i++;
    } while (i<=MAX);
    Console.WriteLine("The test scores of the students are:");
    Console.WriteLine("students \t scores \t");
//And I need to repeat the list of student names and scores here
```

Comment: Besides the bug Robert Harvey pointed out, you are overwriting the same item in the two arrays again and again. Replace `0` index with `i` index…

Comment: You're also assiging to `score` twice in a row. Plus that is in a loop, so not sure what you are hoping to use `score` value for.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 4):

This line of code:

```
string student = parsedInput[0] = students[0];
```

is going to copy `students[0]` into `parsedInput[0]` *first.*  So you're losing your parsed input.

Instead, try:

```
string student = parsedInput[0];
students[0] = student;
```

If that is, in fact, your intent.  It's seldom a good idea to do two assignments in the same line of code.

It is likely that you really want to use `i` instead of `0` in your indexers, as in `parsedInput[i]` and `students[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

What Robert wrote is true. Additionally, you don't use the loop variable i to store each student in a different "slot" of the array, so you're overwriting everything currently in the same place. And the declaration of the array must be outside of the loop, otherwise it will erase it in each iteration.

Summing up the changes required to your C# code sample, the corrected version looks like this:

```
void Main()
{   
    int MAX = 20;

    var students = new string[MAX];
    var scores = new int[MAX];

    int i=0;
    do {
        Console.Write("Enter the student's name followed by his/her score on the same line:");
        var studentAndScore = Console.ReadLine();
        if (studentAndScore == "")
        {
            break;
        }

        string[] parsedInput = studentAndScore.Split();     
        students[i] = parsedInput[0];       
        scores[i] = int.Parse(parsedInput[1]);

        i++;
    } while (i<MAX);
    Console.WriteLine("The test scores of the students are:");
    Console.WriteLine("students \t scores \t");
    for(int k=0; k<i; k++) {
        Console.WriteLine("Student: {0}, Score: {1}", students[k], scores[k]);
    }
}
```

Note that I am using the value of `i` in the `for` statement rather than `MAX`, because the user can break out of the do loop by entering a blank line. And `i` always contains the # of items, which have been entered previously.

Of course, this code does not yet contain any error handling, which would be required in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two lists...

```
var names = new List<String>();
var scores = new List<Int32>();
```

...read the input into the lists...

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("student/score: ");

    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        var parts = input.Split();

        names.Add(parts[0]);
        scores.Add(Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
    }
    else
    {
         break;
    }
}
```

... and output the lists.

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", names[i], scores[i]);
}
```

And of course add a lot of error handling. Or you could use a dictionary but I am not really sure about the guarantees you get regarding the ordering of the items.

```
var data = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("student/score: ");

    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        var parts = input.Split();

        data.Add(parts[0], Int32.Parse(parts[1]));
    }
    else
    {
         break;
    }
}

foreach (var entry in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```